# How can I access an array of commands w/ Cli in Go?

Tags: go

Currently using [Codegangsta's Cli Library](https://github.com/codegangsta/cli). I run a command like so:

```
myGoProgram arg1 arg2 arg3 --flag1 flag1arg
```

Running

```
app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) {
        fmt.Println("Context: ", c.Args())
}
```

returns: `[arg1 arg2 arg3 --flag1 flag1arg]` ([c.Args()'s return type](https://godoc.org/github.com/codegangsta/cli#Context.Args))

How can I access `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3`, but not `--flag1` or `flag1arg`? Do I have to iterate through this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I did was create two arrays of the same contents and just removed elements accordingly to create an array of only the raw commands.

```
func noFlagCliArgs(cliArgs []string) []string {
    a := cliArgs
    for pos, arg := range cliArgs {
        if strings.Compare(string(arg[0]), "-") == 0 {
            // Cut out two to get rid of flag and its argument
            a = append(a[:pos], a[pos+2:]...)
        }
    }
    return a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not have your flags defined correctly, see this example I cooked up:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/codegangsta/cli"
)

func main() {
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Name = "so-example"
    app.Usage = "Demonstrate CLI usage"

    app.Commands = []cli.Command{
        {
            Name:    "one",
            Usage:   "first thing",
            Flags: []cli.Flag{
                cli.StringFlag{
                    Name:  "test",
                    Value: "foobar",
                    Usage: "something cool",
                },
            },
            Action: func(c *cli.Context) {
                fmt.Println("completed task", c.Command.Name, " with args ", c.Args())
                if (c.String("test") != "foobar") {
                    fmt.Println("Where'd foobar go?")
                }
            },
        },
        {
            Name:    "two",
            Usage:   "second thing",
            Flags: []cli.Flag{
                cli.StringFlag{
                    Name:  "test",
                    Value: "foobar",
                    Usage: "something cool",
                },
            },
            Action: func(c *cli.Context) {
                fmt.Println("completed task", c.Command.Name, " with args ", c.Args())
                fmt.Println("Testing value:", c.String("test"))
                if (c.String("test") != "foobar") {
                    fmt.Println("Where'd foobar go?")
                }
            },
        },
    }
    app.Run(os.Args)
}
```

### Quick examples:

#### Without flag

```
$ ./sandbox two foo bar hello world
completed task two  with args  [foo bar hello world]
Testing value: foobar
```

#### With flag

```
$ ./sandbox two foo bar hello world --test "see"
completed task two  with args  [foo bar hello world]
Testing value: see
Where'd foobar go?
```